# What Tiling Window Manager for Windows do you recommend?

Tags: windows, window-manager, awesome-wm

What is the best [tiling window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager) for Windows?

I'm looking for something like [`awesome`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awesome_(window_manager)).

It would be nice if it removes the title bar and has "comfortable" shortcut keys (for me that's `vi` keys, but feel free to use your own reference). Open source would be a plus.

Comment: Seems like a very constructive question to me.

Comment: I really like [WinDivvy](http://mizage.com/windivvy/). It has a really nice GUI but it cost a bit.

Comment: Don't see how this isn't construtive

Comment: @MikeMcFarland Asking for "what's the best…?" is the prime example of a non-constructive question, since everyone defines this differently.

Comment: MaxTo is a pretty good tiling manager, you can get it for as cheap as $10.  http://maxto.net/   Divvy isn't bad either.

Comment: Do not use SplitView, it doesn't work that well.  When hitting arrows they don't move with the window.  The Win + Arrow key moves the window around erratically.  It's all around just buggy.

Comment: everyone DOES NOT define 'best' differently. So there there are billions of people in the world there are billions of definitions? There are commonalities in definitions, there is information to be conveyed here, these are important fact to be conveyed, and the Nazi-like quest for 'canonical answers' and no subjectivity whatsoever is the most horrible policy of this site. It's really too bad.

Comment: FYI [Tiling window manager for Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/34006/903)

Answer (score 54):

[bug.n](https://github.com/fuhsjr00/bug.n) is nice, and Open Source. :-)

Comment: +1; I tried it, and love it.  I especially like the fact that it can be disabled very easily (windows+shift+q) and is customizable through its config files. Oh, and being a DWM clone doesn't hurt :D

Comment: Yep, really doesn't :-)

Comment: I don't know why uoi're linking to freenet (blocked by my proxy), but Wikipedia links to http://www.autohotkey.net./~joten/ for bug.n

Comment: It doesn't work well with Chrome, does it? The tabs simply disappear.

Comment: @Babu: It's Ctrl+WinKey+Q

Comment: It is also very confusing - there is no tutorial on how to use it, or documentation that I can see anywhere.

Comment: Also it claims multiple monitor support, but it's very, very bad support. Even on one monitor it's a bit buggy, not as awesome as Awesome. bun.g doesn't show running programs on the taskbar like you would expect.

Comment: I tried bug.n and loved its simplicity and responsiveness plus, of course, ability to easily quit/ disable while I was on the learning curve. I noticed of late, however, that Office 2013 apps don't play well with it - e.g., decorations are not removed, closing a window makes it pop up again, etc. Also I see the "desktop" is considered as one of the windows for tiling purposes leading to a "hole".

Comment: agree, this is the best I've seen but it doesn't work well in Chrome and Firefox. It is also confusing. There is no clear description how to change the config files. I'm already trying for hours to disable the mouse movement when I click on a layout. Can't find it.

Comment: @drozzy, Yeah.. I have been working for a few hours tryign to understand bug.n as well. not sure whether its the 9.0 version.. but couldnt understand whats going on.. I starting working on a tutorial here.. as a way to educate myseff as well as create something useful so future users can get up to speed quicker. Feel free to contribute.. A lot of windows users maynot be familiar with dwm or the master/stack model of arranging windows.. so I put that information in there as well.. Let me know wht you guys think, as well https://github.com/alphaCTzo7G/bug.n/blob/master/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: @alpha_989 Did you ever finish the tutorial?  The link doesn't work :(  I'm still struggling with bug.n on Windows 7, windows flashing and jumping every where, and I can't figure out the config file.  I was hoping it'd be like i3 which only took me a few minutes to get used to.

Answer (score 30):

It doesn't remove title bars, but you can use [Winsplit Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/) to use create keyboard shortcuts for regions ("tiles") on your screen.

Comment: This, sir, is the best thing since sliced bread

Comment: Bummer, the site is dead. Can still get it from other download sites, just not the main one.

Comment: It is discontinued.

Comment: Looks like another company providing a similar product has poached that URL now

Answer (score 26):

From a [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager#3rd_party_addons):

> - WindowSizer - Tiles windows (shareware)
> - WinSplit - Tiles windows using keyboard shortcuts (freeware)
> - HashTWM - Tiling window manager with automatic tiling (MIT/X11)
> - GridMove - Tiles and arranges windows on sophisticated layouts with hotkeys and multi-monitor support (freeware/donationware)
> - bug.n - Dynamic, tiling window manager, which tries to clone the functionality of dwm (see list of X window managers) (GPL)
> - MaxTo - Tiles windows on user-defined grid by intercepting windows that are maximized or using hotkeys. Supports multi-monitor setups (shareware)
> - Twinsplay - Tiles windows using keyboard shortcuts (trial/closed source)

Comment: +1 MaxTo isn't free, but it's pretty darn cheap considering how well it works.

Comment: +1 AquaSnap (not in answer but in the wikipedia list)

Comment: @laggingreflex: Wikipedia articles are susceptible to modifications ;)