# Tiling Window Manager for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, window-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Tiling Window Manager for Windows do you recommend?](https://superuser.com/questions/10347/what-tiling-window-manager-for-windows-do-you-recommend)

What is the recommended tiling window manager for Windows 7?

In the past I had used Awesome on my Linux box but I am currently using Windows as my primary workstation.

I should add that my setup consists of 3 monitors, hence, I am looking for a multi-monitor friendly solution.