# Smarter Window Opening?

Tags: windows-7

I doubt if a tool like this exists, but it would be nice. So many times, I open an explorer window, and then another explorer window or a different app so that I can drag something from the explorer window into that app to open it, or to copy the file to my USB stick. Every single time one window opens on top of the other. I have TWO monitors, a lot of screen real-estate... why does Windows find it necessary to put the new window the one place I don't want it?

Is there an app that can look at the last window I had active, and then when a new window opens, *put it somewhere else*? Like, on the opposite monitor, or at least beside the other window?

Comment: This would be good to have. I'd post an answer if I knew one!! I know that in Linux, there are some great window managers (what the explorer shell in Windows is) that have user-configurable options regarding where to put new windows = exactly what you're looking for, but different OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows7 you can <kbd>win</kbd><kbd>left</kbd> for the first explorer, then <kbd>win</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> for the 2nd explorer which you then <kbd>win</kbd><kbd>right</kbd> to the right side of the screen.

If that does not satisfy you: look into something like

[What Tiling Window Manager for Windows do you recommend?](https://superuser.com/questions/10347/what-tiling-window-manager-for-windows-do-you-recommend)

and http://www.autohotkey.net/~joten/bug.n/help.html to let others do the placement of the windows for you.

Comment: Not bad! Didn't know that was built right into windows... I'll have to try and remember that.

Answer (score 3):

You might love [WinSplit Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/) together with [AllSnap](http://ivanheckman.com/allsnap/) and optionally [Finestra Virtual Desktops](http://vdm.codeplex.com/).

[image]