# Split-Screen Between Shell and X-Windows in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, xorg, window

Is there a way to split the screen between a program running through the X-server and a standard text-based terminal? I am operating under Cygwin under Windows.

The solution should be as keyboard-based as possible.

---

```
[Screen A - Running xeyes         ] || [Screen B - Running bash shell #2]
```

---

Then, through a single (or a few) keystroke(s), I am able to switch the focus on the left side (just like in GNU Screen between different screen windows):

```
[Screen A - Running bash shell #1 ] || [Screen B - Running bash shell #2]
```

The solution already exists if all the programs are bash shells. Using GNU Screen, I can switch between Bash shell 1 or bash shell 2 or bash shell 3. Essentially what I want to do is run simultaneously and view simultaneously the output, a X-server-based program AND a bash shell. For example, the left side might be a .pdf document and the right side a bash shell. And I frequently and rapidly switch the focus on the left side between different pdf documents.

Related is the tile-window-manager programs for linux, I'm not sure if I can run those under cygwin (openbox?).

Thanks for your input.

Comment: It seems like you should be able to use a Windows tiling window manager to achieve what you want (http://superuser.com/questions/10347/what-tiling-window-manager-for-windows-do-you-recommend lists some).  Alternatively, run bash in xterm, a tiling X WM, and use a full screen Xserver session...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can start the X server in multiwindow : each X application has its own window. So the window manager is MS Windows.

```
 X -multiwindow &
 export DISPLAY=:0
 xclock&
```